# Creating table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When you create a table in rails, does the primary key default to :id?

I am trying to access a row in the table by :id, and it's taking over 3 seconds to return the result.

The table contains BLOBs on the order of 5-20Mb and whenever I directly reference a row using ModleName.find(:id), the operation takes a long time.

If anyone has suggestions on how to speed up this process I"m all ears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary key is the `id` by default but it doesn't mean any `index` has been created.

To achieve that simply add this kind of line in a `migration` file:

```
add_index(table_name, column_names, options)
```

[See doc here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html).

Comment: You answered the next question I was going to ask: "is an index created?". I created the index and I see a reduction of around 200-300ms to run the find operation. 

Do you have any suggestions on how to manage the BLOBs?

Comment: sorry, no special advice here: I tend to avoid using blobs

Comment: The primary key (on MySQL) is the fastest way to access a record, you don't have to add any index for speeding your ModelName.find(:id) query, it will be useless. Your problem is because of the size of your BLOB data, and as almost everybody told you already, you should not use the database to store large binary data, use the filesystem and store a path or any other pointer your table.

Comment: Could I know why I've been granted a -1?

Comment: Because i disagree on answering the op to add an index, he said that he is using the primary key to fetch his data, why would he need to add any index for this on his table ? Also if he mistakenly add an index on his BLOB column it will be totally overkill...Anyway storing large binary data in DB is bad practice so this should not happen at all ;-)

Comment: Thanks @apneadiving. Unfortunately heroku is readonly so I'll have to find another solution, like storing the file on S3 or something.

Answer (score 4):

> When you create a table in rails, does the primary key default to :id?

Yes

> The table contains BLOBs on the order of 5-20Mb and whenever I
> directly reference a row using ModleName.find(:id), the operation
> takes a long time.
>
> If anyone has suggestions on how to speed up this process I"m all ears

Don't store actual files in the database. You'll run into performance issues like you are right now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Rails does the primary key default to :id

First make sure the select query runs up to the speed you wanted in the MySQL command line itself.

Because once I had an issue, where MySQL query itself is slow, as if the MySQL query is slow, there is nothing Rails can do about it.

Anyway as Chirs pointed out, never store files in the table, unless otherwise you have a very good reason to.